# How to make programmatically added annotation sub-view scrollable over keyboard

Tags: android, pdf, annotations, scrollview, androidpdfviewer

I want to use annotation on my PDF view.

For loading PDF, I have used [AndroidPdfViewer library](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer)

Now I have added view programmatically over it.

**ScrollView** - If I use `scrollview` which is having edit text, as soon as my keyboard opens, my custom added `scrollview` resizes to the available screen area. Now my PDF view and custom view are not sync and i tried giving custom offset any many other provided solution, but not working in my case. So How can I make both in sync or in other words make both view scroll to same y position.

I am setting `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in manifest.

activity_main.xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Programmatically added layout is,

```
     ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
            scrollView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100000));
            scrollView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.bg2));

  EditText et = new EditText(this);
                et.setPadding(10, 10, 0, 0);
                et.setTextSize(8);
                et.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
                et.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edittext_border));

scrollview.addView(et);

pdfView.addView(scrollview); // pdfView = findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
```

So how to make pro-grammatically added annotation sub-view scroll-able over keyboard or make pdf and annotation view scroll in sync while keyboard is open.